# Snyk reporting vulnerabilities in Apache-Beam 2.52.0

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, snyk

We have Snyk integrated with our Python repository to identify any vulnerabilities in any of the libraries we are using. I am trying to add the dependency of apache-beam 2.52.0 (latest version) to pyproject.toml file. However, Synk is reporting a vulnerability during the build process in pyarrow  11.0.0 which Apache beam uses internally. This is also causing the build to fail.

```
Pin pyarrow@11.0.0 to pyarrow@14.0.1 to fix
  ✗ Deserialization of Untrusted Data (new) [Critical Severity][https://security.snyk.io/vuln/SNYK-PYTHON-PYARROW-6052811] in pyarrow@11.0.0
    introduced by apache-beam@2.52.0 > pyarrow@11.0.0
```

I tried going to back to Apache beam 2.44.0 which uses pyarrow 9 internally but same vulnerability is being reported with all the versions. Is there any workaround for this?
(I might not be able to disable Synk or add any exclusions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should already be handled by https://github.com/apache/beam/issues/29392 with Beam 2.52.0 as long as pyarrow_hotfix is installed. You can ignore Synk.

Comment: Yes, added it to exclusion in Snyk